# Text or Icon in action bar, stuck with the 3 dots

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I'm making an android app in Eclipse. I want to place a text or icon in the action bar, but when I am writing in menu.xml, which looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
        android:id="@+id/createnew"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="CREATE"/>
   </menu>
```

it puts it in the options menu. I want to separate it.

I see this in the app when I run it:
(sorry can't post pictures because I don't have enough rep)

[image]

I want to CREATE next to the option menu like this for example:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the native action bar, or AppCompat. IOW, are you inheriting from `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: @CommonsWare im working with a friend, he wrote the most part of the code, this is the android theme: Theme.AppCompat.Light and in MainActivity i see this : public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  so i suppose you mean this?

Comment: @user3700721 Just a little FYI, [Wordpress for Android is open source](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android), since you're wondering about their app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the AppCompat Actionbar, you need to use a custom namespaced `showAsAction` attribute.

It should look something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/createnew"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="CREATE"/>
</menu>
```

Note that this uses `yourapp:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`. This is because the `showAsAction` attribute is not available on pre-Honeycomb devices and is provided by the support library.

For more information, read the [Action Bar developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: okey seriously, youre my hero. it worked. Also do you know how i can add two options when i click on it?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by this line

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

That tells Android to put it up there if it's going to fit nicely.  If you want it up there no matter the fit use

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```